# ASP .Net Core MVC RoleManager Roles To List Retun Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I trying to get all role exists and do with this code:

```
private readonly RoleManager<IdentityRole> _roleManager;

public ActionResult ManageRole(string username)
{
...
var roleNamesList = _roleManager.Roles.ToList();
...
}
```

but in debug I got error :

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Can you help any solution please, I'm begginer.
Thanks.

> Solved : I must initialize _roleManager in first YourController()
>   function

```
private readonly RoleManager<IdentityRole> _roleManager;

public ManageController(
        ...,
        RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager,
        ...)
        {
            ...;
            _roleManager = roleManager;
            ...;
        }

public ActionResult ManageRole(string username)
{
...
var roleNamesList = _roleManager.Roles.ToList();
...
}
```

Comment: has `_roleManager` been initialized?

Comment: thanks for respond I initialized _roleManager :
private readonly RoleManager<IdentityRole> _roleManager;

that code is wrong?

Comment: It's only declared there. To initialize you will need to assign it an object.

Comment: how the way I can initialize it? sorry I'm begginer.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397680.aspx

Comment: Yes I initialized it, in RolesData Model :
public class RolesData
{  
private static readonly string[] Roles = new string[] { "Administrator", "PowerUser", "UserManager", "Invalid", "Valid", "Developer" };
...
foreach (var role in Roles)
                    {
                        if (!await roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(role))
                        {
                            await roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(role));
                        }
                    }
...
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get it like this:

```
context.Roles.ToList()
```

Comment: I tried this and get same error.

private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
public ActionResult ManageRole(string username)
{
...
var roleNamesList = _context.Roles.ToList();
...
}

any solution with the code I did?

Comment: You did not initialize the dbContext, you have to initialize it in the constructor like this:

public YourController()
        {
            _context = new ApplicationDbContext();
        }

Comment: I did it man, but in another controller that have initialized _context, I got all rolename with this solution!
in my current woriking controller I got some problem with initialize that _context I wonder why (I'm begginer).

Anyway this solution is helpful, thanks.